# Android app logs not logging in release build

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I am using android.util.Log for logging in to my Android application. I am storing these logs to a text file for analyzing the production issues. but recently these my application-level logs are stopped writing even in Android console also. I did not do changes in build.gradle or proguard file.

I observed logs are printing if disable minifyEnabled or enable debuggable in build.gradle, but these are not recommended.

Kindly please check and suggest any configuration changes required in proguard file build file to correct this.

Please find the release configuration in build.gradle for reference

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
```

Further Update :

I found that it is causing due to the dependencies amazonpay and simpl SDK dependencies added to my project in app.gradle

When I remove these dependencies it is working fine, please suggest me know how I can solve this by retaining the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ProGuard or R8 obfuscation is enabled in your release build. These tools can obfuscate and optimize your code, potentially removing or renaming log statements. To preserve the log statements, you can add appropriate ProGuard or R8 rules. For example, in your ProGuard configuration file (proguard-rules.pro),
you can add: `-keep class android.util.Log { *; }`

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion but I tried this already does not help and this is happening in android 11 and 12

Comment: buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
       }
}

try to add  debuggable true and check that it is working or not.

Comment: Yeah, This works but keeping debuggable true for the release build is not recommended as it have implication with security and reliability of source code

Comment: But another Android app I have is working fine I cross-checked the differences in configuration and experminted. still no luck

Comment: Further Update :

I found that it is causing due to the dependencies amazonpay and simpl SDK dependencies added to my project in app.gradle

When I remove these dependencies it is working fine, please suggest me know how I can solve this by retaining the dependencies